# Laravel auth with MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I'm developing a Laravel 5.7 application with MYSQL database.

My question is, how to authenticate a given user with 'username' and 'password'.

The MYSQL stored procedure accepts these two parameters, and returns 'userLevel' and 'projectID' if the user exists, and 'false' otherwise.

The database can not be modified by any means, so I have to tweak the auth process in Laravel.

**Note:** The 'userLevel' and 'projectID' should be included in `auth()->user()` if auth succeeded. How I'm I supposed to do this?

Comment: can  you clarify your question? is `projectID` different from `processID`?

Comment: @Capt.Teemo Fields, for example.

Comment: This may help: https://medium.com/@smayzes/stored-procedures-in-laravel-60e7cb255fc9